# What is the Maximum Size of PostgreSQL Child Table

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

**What is the maximum size of a PostgreSQL Child Table?**

I saw a limit of 32TB here http://www.postgresql.org/about/, but it does not specify in regards to child tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A child table is still a table so the same limitation would apply.

Comment: Then it makes sense unlimited rows can be stored.  Thanks.